# Scrape MarketWatch with Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am setting up a new Excel spreadsheet with stock tickers and I need to scrape each stock's Ex-Dividend date information from MarketWatch.

This is an example link I need to get the Ex-Dividend date from: 
https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/dxb

I currently use Google Sheet to do this, and this is the code I use:

```
`=REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/"&$A2&"", "list", 23), 13, 1),"Ex-Dividend Date", "")`
```

I have tried finding the representing functions in Excel, but could not end up with anything that actually works. So is there a way I can scrape this information in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/dxb"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.document.all
   If itm.classname = "kv__value kv__primary" Then
      .Range("C" & RowCount) = itm.classname
      .Range("D" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)
      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   End If
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

If I were you, I would loop through cells that had all the stocks you want to run this against, and copy/paste each into the query above.  That way, you can grab ex-dividend dates for all the stocks you want.